# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socceraction.classification'

Tags: python

I trying to replicate [passing-networks-in-python](https://github.com/Friends-of-Tracking-Data-FoTD/passing-networks-in-python) repositories outcome. I have installed the dependencies listed in requirements.txt and downloaded StatsBomb and Metrica Sports data into the eventing and tracking folder.

However, when trying to run prepare_vaep.py I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socceraction.classification'` returned.

Could this be an issue with the version I am using (3.7.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `socceraction` module was updated and does not include `classification` packages (or were moved). Either update the `import socceraction.classification` to correct import or install certain version using `pip install socceractiopn==<version_num>`

Check [socceraction Github](https://github.com/ML-KULeuven/socceraction/tree/master/socceraction) for source code

Here is a specific [commit](https://github.com/ML-KULeuven/socceraction/commit/fb61108feaf9326097e117aed614833883cb8546) in package structure changes

EDIT: change any `import socceraction.classification` to `import socceraction.vaep` (change any children that use `classification` as well) if you want to use latest code.

Comment: Taking awhile but it looks like it's working now, thank you!